# Ripple secret key

Tags: wallet, address, ripple, bip32-hd-wallets, ripple-api

I am adding Ripple to my HD Wallet.
To be compatible with other HD wallet, I need to use bip32/bip44 paths.
So I will use such approaches:
https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39
https://github.com/you21979/node-ripple-bip32

But these libraries generate private key that is different from Ripple's secret key. Public/private key pairs are just like the bitcoins addresses.
How can I generate secret key from this private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deriving a key using this method, the ripple secret key does not exist.

There is no compatibility because the derivation algorithm is different.